# Layers of confusion about Deja-Dup encrypted backups

Tags: backup, encryption, gnupg, deja-dup, duplicity

I've been happily rolling along with my Deja-Dup backups to remote Google Drive for a month or so. At some point, I may or may not have entered a passphrase. I may or may not have had a GPG key at the time.

Recently, I put my home folder in source control, and somehow lost the `.gnupg` and `.ssh` folders. I got the latter back, but I'm not sure about the GPG, which I've only started using in recent months.

So, this week I enter a passphrase. Later, i get the following error in a dialog, each time.

```
Backup Failed

GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: gcry_kdf_derive failed: Invalid data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

I'm not sure if my backups are encrypted, or if there are backups with different passwords, or what.  Running `ps aux | grep duplicity` yields the following, abbreviated command. Please note the last three arguments, `gio...`, `no-encryption`, & `no-use-agent`.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
self     10022  1.1  0.1 272576 27708 ?        Ssl  08:29   0:00  |   \_ \
                 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/duplicity collection-status   \
                 [--exclude=/home/self/eg1 --exclude=/home/self/eg2 ...] \ 
                 --include=/home/self                                    \
                 gio+google-drive://self@gmail.com/homedisco             \
                 --no-encryption                                         \
                 --gpg-options=--no-use-agent                            \
                 ...
```

Please help me figure out if I have inaccessible backups and need to start over entirely. Thank you.